# Storing dates in mongodb format

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date

My application has several datepickers and for them i use the format for date as  DD/MM/YYYY
Then I send this date to my nodejs backend which stores the data object in mongodb.

In future my application would need to filter data based on date ranges. For this reason i don't want to store dates as strings. Instead I would like to store them in the format that will allow me to perform range based queries on a collection.

What is my best choice here considering the fact that I cannot change the date format on the frontend?

Will really appreciate if someone could provide a detailed answer to this for my clear understanding of the concept.

Comment: Use native date objects for your chosen language implementation, they will serialize properly to MongoDB. Very clearly stated in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

On your nodejs backend, you can convert your string date "DD/MM/YYYY" to Date object before put it in mongodb.  something like this:

```
var dateStr = "15/12/2013";   // the 15th of Dec, 2013
var dateArr = dateStr.split('/');

// new Date(YYYY, MM, DD); // note that month starts from 0, so
// you have to subtract 1
var date = new Date(dateArr[2], dateArr[1] - 1, dateArr[0]);
console.log(date);  // output: Sun Dec 15 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
```

This date now is a Date object which you can then save in the mongodb and to query by date range later when needed

Comment: hey ben thanks for reply. How do i go with this if i need to save time as well in the format : 05/22/2014 12:00 PM ??

Comment: You can do: var dateArr = dateStr.split(' '); var dateParts = dateArr[0].split('/'); var timeParts = dateArr[1].split(':'); var amPm = dateArr[2]; var date = new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[0], timeParts[0] + (amPm === 'PM' ? 12 : 0), timeParts[1]);

Comment: I tried the method you suggested and upon retrieval, i got the following date: 2015-10-12T19:08:00.000Z. Now how do i convert it back to the original form. Another issue is that I don't understand how it became 2015 from 2014. Can you please explain if not of much botheration to you?

Comment: when you query from database, you got Date object, so you can do this: var dateStr = date.getDate() + '/' + date.getMonth() + '/' + date.getFullYear() + ' ' + date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes() + ' ' + (date.getHours() >= 0 ? 'PM' : 'AM');   for the year issue, not sure, print out the value before saving it to database and see what you get... also check database itself to see the year in the database

Comment: If your client is in javascript, you can converter your Date() object JSON string (date.toJSON()) and send it to server.  Then in node.js, you just need to do this: var date = new Date(toJSONStringDateFromClient);   this will convert it to date object and ready to put in the database

Comment: try printing the date before converting, after converting, and check the database to see where it when wrong